# Path connectedness of the product topology of Sorgenfrey and cocountable topology

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Let $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T_{[,)}} \times \mathcal{T_{CC}}$ I want to find the connected components of this topology, I already know that Sorgenfrey is not path connected and is totally disconnected. Moreover, the cocountable topology is also not path connected.

Due to this, I cannot directly create a path combining paths of both topologies.

So, is there any path connected component in the product topology?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: If $A \neq \emptyset$ is a (path) connected subset of the product, its projection into the Sorgenfrey line is connected, hence contains exactly one element. Therefore $A$ is homeomorphic to a subset of the cocountable topology of the reals, or where ever you consider it

Answer (score 1):

**The path components of the product are the products of path components.**

Since Sorgenfrey is totally disconnected, all you need  is  to find the path components of the cocountable topology.

---

**Proof:**

Suppose $X = \bigcup_i X_i$ and $Y = \bigcup_j Y_j$ are the path components. Then we can write $Z = \bigcup_{i,j} X_i \times Y_j = \bigcup_{i,j} Z_{ij}$.

I claim $Z_{ij}$ are the path components of the product.

It is straightforward to see each $Z_{ij}$ is path connected.

Now suppose $z(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ is a path from some point in $Z_{ij}$ to some point in $Z_{kl}$. Then we have

$$x(0) \in X_i \qquad y(0) \in Y_j\qquad  x(1) \in X_k\qquad  y(1) \in Y_l$$

If $Z_{ij} \ne Z_{kl}$ then without loss of generality $i \ne k$. Since the projection is continuous $x(t)$ is a path from $X_i$ to $X_k$ which is not allowed. So no such path $z$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

Any path-connected component must be connected.

Suppose $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle c,d\rangle$ are elements of $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{T_{[,)}} \times \mathcal{T_{CC}}$.

If $a\neq b$, then $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle c,d\rangle$ are not in the same connected component. Therefore, they are not in the same path-connected component.

But if $a=b$ and if there is a path $\gamma$ from $\langle a,b\rangle$ to $\langle c,d\rangle$,

by projecting to the $\mathcal{T_{CC}}$ part of $\mathcal{T}$ you can see that there is a path from $c$ to $d$ within $\mathcal{T_{CC}}$. This can be the case only when $c=d$.

Therefore, the path-connected components of $\mathcal{T}$ are precisely singletons.